# swift lazy var with throw init behavior

Tags: swift, throw, lazy-initialization

I am not sure if it is a bug or it is really how things should work?

```
class A {
    init() throws { }
}

class B {
    lazy var instance = A()
}
```

this code compiles without mistakes using XCode 9 and latest `Swift` version, and works perfect unless `Class A` `init()` really throws, then lazy var is null pointer. But shouldn't be this code somehow not be compiled?

Comment: I wonder why compiler not showing anything  !!

Comment: Nice find – I went ahead and [filed a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7862).

Comment: @Hamish thank you, I guess you should post this as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a bug ([SR-7862](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7862)) – you cannot throw errors out of a property initialiser context (and even if you could, you would be required to prefix the call with `try`), therefore the compiler should produce an error.

I have opened a pull request to fix this ([#17022](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/17022)).

**Edit:** The patch has now been cherry-picked to the 4.2 branch, so it'll be fixed for the release of Swift 4.2 with Xcode 10 (and until the release you can [try a 4.2 snapshot](https://swift.org/download/#snapshots)).

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to your question:

> But shouldn't be this code somehow not be compiled?

Well, at some point your code snippet worked without any issue (because -as you mentioned- the class `A` init doesn't actually throws), so it could be **compiled** without any problem. To make it more clear, consider it as a similar case to the following one:

```
let myString: String? = nil
print(myString!) // crashes!
```

it will get compiled just fine! although we all know that it crashes when evaluating `myString!`, i,e we do know it causes a ***run-time*** crash, but that doesn't mean that the compiler should prevent it because it could be valid at some point (for instance if we declare it as `let myString: String? = "Hello"`); Similarly to your case, it could be valid at some point -as mentioned above-.

Usually, for such cases we -as developers- are the responsible to handle it based on what's the desired behavior(s).

---

Referring to this case, we might need to ask:

"How can we implement the `instance` lazy variable to catch an error (with a `do-catch` block)?"

Actually, this code *won't* compile:

```
class B {
    lazy var instance:A = {
        do {
            let myA = try A()
            return myA
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }()
}
```

complaining that:

> Missing return in a closure expected to return 'A'

because obviously reaching the catch block means that there is nothing to be returned. Also, as you mentioned even if you implemented it as

```
lazy var instance = A()
```

you will not get a compile-time error, *however* trying to use it with an actual throwing should leads to run time error:

```
let myB = B()
print(myB.instance) // crash!
```

What I would suggest for resolving this issue is to declare `instance` as lazy *optional* variable:

```
class B {
    lazy var instance:A? = {
        do {
            let myA = try A()
            return myA
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        return nil
    }()
}
```

At this point, if we assume that `A` initializer always throws, trying to access it:

```
let myB = B()
print(myB.instance)
```

should log:

> caught error
>
> nil

without causing any crash. Otherwise, it should works fine, for instance:

```
let myB = B()
myB.instance?.doSomething() // works fine
```

Comment: well, I know all of these basics. The question here is that I declare `A` without `try` keyword, which is weird behaviour for me at least. In your example you use `!` to force unwrap, imagine, that somehow you are allowed to force unwrap without `!`, wouldn't that be strange?